How can I solve NoReverseMatch error in Django?
I'm making the website using Django. I have a comment section for every post. But I am getting the following error.
NoReverseMatch at /comment/create/the-art-of-self-care-prioritizing-your-well-being/

Reverse for 'comment-create' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['comment/create/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\\Z']

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/comment/create/the-art-of-self-care-prioritizing-your-well-being/
Django Version:     5.0.1
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'comment-create' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['comment/create/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\\Z']

Exception Location:     C:\Users\shafa\PycharmProjects\CampusConnect\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 848, in _reverse_with_prefix
Raised during:  comments.views.CommentCreateView
Python Executable:  C:\Users\shafa\PycharmProjects\CampusConnect\.venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     3.12.1
Python Path:    

['C:\\Users\\shafa\\PycharmProjects\\CampusConnect',
 'C:\\Users\\shafa\\PycharmProjects\\CampusConnect',
 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm '
 '2023.2.5\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_display',
 'C:\\Python312\\python312.zip',
 'C:\\Python312\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python312\\Lib',
 'C:\\Python312',
 'C:\\Users\\shafa\\PycharmProjects\\CampusConnect\\.venv',
 'C:\\Users\\shafa\\PycharmProjects\\CampusConnect\\.venv\\Lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm '
 '2023.2.5\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_matplotlib_backend']

Server time:    Mon, 16 Sep 2024 12:56:05 +0000

models.py
class Comment(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()

    author = models.ForeignKey('users.User', related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey('posts.Post', related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author.username + " -> " + self.post.title

views.py
class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.post = Post.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.object.post.slug})

urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('create/<slug:slug>/', views.CommentCreateView.as_view(), name='comment-create'),
]

comment_form.html
<form action="{% url 'comment-create' post.slug %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="flex flex-col gap-2">
        <label for="comment" class="text-lg">Comment</label>
        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="30" rows="4" class="textarea"
                  placeholder="Write your thoughts..."></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Submit</button>
    <p>{{ post.slug }}</p>
    <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
</form>

In the page, I can see the post slug, and post title as I have in the the  tag.
The URL I can see in the browser is http://localhost:8000/comment/create/the-art-of-self-care-prioritizing-your-well-being/ where the-art-of-self-care-prioritizing-your-well-being is the slug.
I tried different ways to pass the slug parameter and cross checking everything. But nothing worked.

Your view doesn't add any object called post to the context so post.slug resolves to an empty string when rendering the template. Check the second duplicate target on how to add that to the context.
